# select statements and loops

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to execute a program with the following flow. I wondered how I could write this properly with oracle pl/sql?

paymentIds is an array of values, originally initialized as a VARRAY.

I'd like to pass variable1 into the "update" statement.

```
procedure reset_finance_interface(paymentIds MyType)
is

  BEGIN

  FOR i IN 1..paymentIds.count LOOP
     variable1 = 
     select id_finance_interface 
     from finance_interface fi
     where fi.interface_id in (paymentIds(i))
     and fi.id_interface_type = 'DC'
     
     update finance_interface fi
     set processed = 0
     ,id_interface_file = null
     ,interfaced=0
     ,interface_date = null
     where
     id_interface_type in ('DC')
     and  id_finance_interface = variable1
     and  processed = 2 --not in (0,1)
     and ok_to_process  = 1;
  END LOOP;     

END;
```

Thanks,

Robert

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `MERGE` statement to get rid of the loops and combine the `SELECT` and `UPDATE` statements:

```sql
procedure reset_finance_interface(paymentIds MyType)
IS
BEGIN
  MERGE INTO finance_interface dst
  USING (
    SELECT column_value AS id
    FROM   TABLE(paymentIDs)
  ) src
  ON (
        src.id                = dst.interface_id
    AND dst.id_interface_type = 'DC'
    AND dst.processed         = 2 --not in (0,1)
    AND dst.ok_to_process     = 1
  )
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
    SET processed         = 0
    ,   id_interface_file = null
    ,   interfaced        = 0
    ,   interface_date    = null;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=dd3ceba34f834661db95ac32ad087236)*